# Facebook Photo Upload Quality

Tags: facebook-graph-api, xcode4, facebook-ios-sdk

Just to be sure it's not my code that's messing things up, I just downloaded and installed the new Facebook iOS SDK 3.0 Beta, and I tested the photo upload in the HelloFacebookSample and even though all it did was upload a 25KB image, the uploaded version does not look as good as the original version in the application.

I also tested with a photograph and the quality was bad.

Is there a way to fix this? When the same image is uploaded to Facebook using Safari on a Mac or iPad 3, the quality is good. So it's something to do with the Facebook iOS SDK.

Anybody experiencing this? Or people just don't notice?

I'm building an iOS app that relies on uploaded images to be of good quality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Facebook recompresses photos uploaded to it.  As far as I know, nothing can be done about it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the quality only *appears* to be good if you upload the image using Safari.

In actuality, Facebook forces image recompression, even if you check "High quality" when uploading.

The best you can do is to [double the source image resolution](http://www.vancouverpov.ca/wp/social-media/tips-to-improve-facebook-cover-photo-quality/), and for solid colors, try to introduce noise. Details in this [GD.SE question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/facebook-ways-to-preserve-image-quality-of-uploaded-images)

Note that the trick of uploading images <100kb has no longer been working, since at least [June 2012](http://www.vancouverpov.ca/wp/social-media/tips-to-improve-facebook-cover-photo-quality/#comment-5483).